# Amazon EC2 unexpected billing amount

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-ebs

I´m quite new with Amazon Web Services. Some months ago, I created a m3.medium instance on demand. According to AWS EC2 prices, this instance is 0.077$/hour. This means 55,44$/month (november). However, I got a billing of 74.76$ (91.12$ with taxes).

I guess I have some service that I´m missing and maybe they are charging me:

In example, I have an Elastic Load Balancer. Am I getting charged for that? Actually, I have realized I had two ELB. It looks like I created it another one for testing purposes and I forgot it there.

I also have an Elastic Block Store (EBS) with 8GB of size. Am I getting charged for that? Do I really need it?

When I check my billing status, I don´t see any reference to these both two services. So, I guess they are included in the EC2 billing, right?

I don´t know where I got the idea that when you start an EC2 instances, an ELB and EBS was included with no additional charges.

As you can see, I´m quite lost with these services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Billing information is available from the account menu (in the top-right, next to the Region menu). It will display a simple breakdown of charges by service:

[image: Billing summary]

More detailed billing information is available by clicking the "Bill Details" link (in the top-right). It will show a breakdown of charges by service for any selected month:

[image: Billing detail]

EBS charges are included under "Elastic Compute Cloud":

[image]

To answer your questions:

- [Elastic Load Balancer pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/pricing/)
- [Elastic Block Store (EBS) pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/): This is the disk storage for Amazon EC2. You will be charged for any volumes from the time they are created until they are deleted.

There is also a [**Free Usage Tier**](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) that includes 30GB of EBS storage each month in your first year (amongst other services). If you use services within this free tier, there will be no charge.

Comment: I didn´t see the details link. Now, It´s clear. The unexpected extra charge comes from the second ELB I created and forgot to remove.